# Linear Algebra. Is the function one-to-one, onto, invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by

$$
f\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   x  \\
   y
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{x^2} - {y^2}}  \\
   {2xy}
\end{array}} \right)
$$

Is $f$ one-to-one? Is $f$ onto? Is $f$ invertible?

Please help me I'm stuck in my Linear Algebra class.

Comment: do you mean$$f\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x^2-y^2\\2xy\end{bmatrix}$$?

Comment: If $x=1$ and $y=0$, the value of the function is the same as if $x=-1$ and $y=0$.  So it's not one-to-one.  I believe it's _locally_ one-to-one at every point except at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: yes precisely, I know what what one-to-one and onto means, but I don't know how to apply that to this function.

Comment: The tags need fixing, I think.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint 1*:  $$f\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{pmatrix}=f\begin{pmatrix} -x \\ -y \\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

*Hint 2*:  Check if $$\begin{pmatrix} x^2-y^2 \\ 2xy \\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ \end{pmatrix}$$ has solutions for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: *cough* Pythagoras

Comment: so now I know that f is not one-to-one since input of x and y give me same output as -x and -y. But how do I prove it is onto or not?

Comment: @Mark that is what Hint 2 is for ...

Comment: Indeed.  I found it easier to resolve the $b=0$ case separately; then assume $b \neq 0$.  Afterwards, we can take the second equation and rearrange to get $y=...$ and substitute into the first equation.

Comment: Is there anyway that we can prove this with graph?

Comment: Hmm... you can get intuition from a graph, but not a proof.  If you end up using the same method I used (there might be better methods), once $y$ is eliminated, you'll end up with some function $f_b(x)=a$ containing an unknown constant $b$, which you'll need to prove is onto for all values of $b \neq 0$.  I'd prove it by showing it's continuous on a certain interval and has limits $\pm \infty$ at the endpoints of the interval.

Comment: so I have substituted y=b/2x to first equation and I've got a=x^2-(b^2)/(4x^2). When b=0, a=x^2. And I don't know how to go on. Could you help me?

Comment: Provided $b \neq 0$, we know $b^2>0$.  The function $f_b(x)=x^2-(b^2)/(4x^2)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ [we could argue this by arguing $x^2$ and $1/x^2$ are continuous on this interval (but it's probably enough, for most purposes, to merely recognise this)].  Now we can show that $f_b(x)$ is onto: by showing that $f_b(x) \rightarrow -\infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ from the positive side, and $f_b(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: So that was what you meant by taking b=0 case separately. Now it makes sense. We know that when b=0, a=x^2 and every (a,b) can be defined by (x,y). Furthermore, we can prove that the function is onto when b is not 0 through proving that a=x^2-(b^2)/(4x^2) is continuous on every points except b=0 which we proved earlier.